# Bluemix Monitoring and Analytics service - where did the message column go?

Tags: logging, monitoring, ibm-cloud

In the **Bluemix Monitoring and Analytics** service, on the **Log Analysis** tab, in the **grid view** of results, there used to be a **message** column which contained just the text of the logged messages.  Now that column is gone and has been replaced with a **logRecord** column which also contains the **datetime** of the message.  By including the date and time of the message in this column and no longer including a message-only column, you can no longer plot a meaningful chart of message frequency. I checked the grid view configuration link to see if maybe the message-only column was still available, but just no longer shown by default, but it was not listed as an option there. Can we get a message-only column back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As services evolve in Bluemix the UI's will change and add or remove features.  This is natural in the progression of a project.  I can definitely share your feedback with the Monitoring and Analytics team.